# Android AES/CBC encryption

Tags: java, android, encryption, openssl, aes

Currently I'm using AES/CBC encryption using the javax.crypto.cipher library, however, I'm finding its a little too slow. It takes anywhere between 45s-1m to decrypt a 10 minute .mp4 video file.

Is there a better way to do this on Android? I'm looking around and found some posts about openssl but is it really that much faster?

Any links, helpful posts and/or comments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "10 minute mp4" means absolutely nothing. a 1x1 pixel that never changes is going to be a miniscule file, while a 10minute 4k resolution of pure static is going to be huge. aes doesn't care what the data is. it'd take as long to encrypt/decrypt a 10meg .gif as it would a 10meg .txt or any other 10 meg file.

Comment: is there any native library to get a better resolution for this problem? The main issue is that the app is a video recorder and it might be the case that the video length is 1hr or even more, in which case the decryption is going to be way longer.

Answer (score 1):

Use streaming instead of file decryption. If you stream the video you can simply perform the decryption of the video as you need it. If you use CTR or CBC mode you can even skip to a specific place within the stream, although it will take some additional tricks to make that happen.

Leaving decryption to the default provider should be first choice, but you can certainly speed up things using a native decryption library.

Comment: Do you know of any native libraries that I can use?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not.

Answer (score 0):

Willing to decrypt the entire video before to start playing exposes the user to a noticeable delay. You should consider a streaming architecture.

A typical design involves the javax.crypto.CipherInputStream class and a local http instance. There is no class for an http server in the SDK, you have to implement your own or look for an existing library similar to LocalSingleHttpServer.

It looks like:

```
mServer = new LocalSingleHttpServer();
mServer.setCipher(myGetCipher());
mServer.start();
path = mServer.getURL(path);
mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
mVideoView.start();
```